# Seeding a rails model with an array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand that the answer may be in similar answers that I've read but I do not yet have the knowledge power to draw a solution from them.

I'm trying to seed a column in a rails model with an array:

```
["N1", "N2", "N3", "N4", "N5", etc ]
```

Each value will represent a new line (or entry? not sure of the correct terminology) in the database column.

Currently, similar to what has been suggested in a similar posts, I'm using:

```
[above array].each do |pc| 
    Postcodes.create!({ pcode => pc}) 
end
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Postcodes
```

I've tried un-pluralising the model name and also un-capitalising but this does not seem to help.

db:schema:

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151211095938) do

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.string   "email"
t.string   "password_digest"
t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
```

end

end

Model:

```
class Postcode < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: can you post your model post_code.rb file and your db schema

Comment: Model names in Rails are usually singular. Try `Postcode.create ...`

Comment: What is the name of the class that represents such model?

Comment: Capitalisation didn't seem to work either...

Comment: Take @spickermann's advice.  Try `Postcode.create!({ pcode => pc}) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is names `Postcode`, not `Postcodes` (not the plural `s`). The following should work:

```
codes = ["N1", "N2", "N3", "N4", "N5"]

codes.each do |code|
  Postcode.create!(pcode: code) 
end
```

Comment: Thanks guy's but I'm now getting a different error, I try to seed and then it asks me to migrate the db again, when I rake db I get a new error. I think I better try and figure it out before asking for more advice.